# Applying for visa after entry refusal (full time student)

Tags: visas, uk, international-travel, us-citizens

I was denied entry last year for insufficient funds (I was trying to stay for 6 months to be with my boyfriend...I know, what a great plan) So anyways, I was told I am welcomed back but should wait at least 6 months. They also said a visa would help. I’m not sure what to do...since I waited more than long enough to return, if I have proof of funds for the two weeks I’m staying and a return flight back will I run into any issues? I have most definitely learned my lesson, it just sucks it was the hard way. Btw: I’m planning a visit in December for 2 weeks for the holidays!

I am a US Citizen.

Answer (score 0):

Since you was denied entry for the first time, it is safe to apply visa first.

There will be less chance for another refused entry, as your circumstances will be evaluated beforehand. Make sure all the documents are in order.

Answer (score 0):

Official advice on https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/usa/tourism is that you may want to apply for a visa if you’ve previously been denied entry.

If you do attempt visa-free entry, as well as having a return ticket you should bring the same documents you’d need to apply for a visa, to show to officers at the UK border. So, you’d need eg bank statements, proof of ties to the US (employment contract, pay slips), letter from your boyfriend proving accommodation.

Comment: If I do attempt to renter as a visa free national and just bring everything I would bring to apply for a visa, would my chances be better. ALSO: I am a full-time student I.e money does not come easy to me unless I do decide to pick up some work. I know this is not great but it’s just my life right now.

Comment: Yes, if you have a full set of paperwork your chances of getting visa-free entry must surely be better than when you arrived without proof of sufficient funds. But with one denial already on your record no-one can say for sure if attempting entry on that basis will be problem-free.